# No line breaks inside WordPress MCE (editor)

Tags: wordpress

Something that I have noticed is in the MCE editor in WordPress when using ENTER multiple times the editor doesn't save this. It just is one line break.

What could be the cause of this and how do I resolve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Shift+Enter`(windows)/`Shift+Return`(mac) in `WYSIWYG` editor usually inserts one `<br/>` tag.

Answer (score 2):

set the following in the js/tinymce/tiny_mce.js file (if you are using `Tiny MCE`)

```
this.defParam("force_br_newlines", true);
this.defParam("force_p_newlines", false);
this.defParam("convert_newlines_to_brs", true);
```

Comment: I only have a minified version of that file. How do I know where to insert it there?

Answer (score 1):

Try going into the text editor (not WYSIWYG) and try a (br) tag. Look what happens otherwise try 
 for two breaks.

Comment: It works, but why can I not use the WYSIWYG editor to add a line break extra?

Comment: There could be hundreds of explanations... Theme issues, wordpress outdated... Just try to break it in the text editor and switch back to WYSIWYG. If that works, just keep doing that as your solution. Otherwise I'd advice to disable plug-ins and see if that causes the bug. Maybe an reinstall would do the trick (if your website is small and easy to backup)